# getting error in oracle 009933 sql command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, table-alias

here is my query by I didn't understand why it is not working.

```
  select o.MFR, o.PRODUCT, c.company, p.PRICE 
    from ORDERS AS o 
    inner join customers AS c on c.CUST_NUM = o.CUST
    inner join PRODUCTS AS p On p.MFR_ID = o.MFR 
    where o.CUST in ('2111','2112','2105','2119') and o.AMOUNT < '3000' 
    order by c.company DESC;
```

Comment: What's the data type of `o.AMOUNT`?

Comment: it is number...

Comment: tried that too but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove as from alias

```
select o.MFR, o.PRODUCT, c.company, p.PRICE 
from ORDERS  o 
inner join customers  c on c.CUST_NUM = o.CUST
inner join PRODUCTS  p On p.MFR_ID = o.MFR 
where o.CUST in ('2111','2112','2105','2119') and o.AMOUNT < '3000' 
order by c.company DESC;
```

oracle does not supports in the FROM it support as on select column